# Getting Rows in the form of Column Names

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

Input table format in SQL Server 2008 :

```
            *Name*                                 *Department*

1)          abcd                                    IT
2)          abcd                                    CTECH
3)          abcd                                    MECH
4)          uvw                                     SAP
5)          uvw                                     Informatica
```

Desired output result:

```
         Name     Department1      Department2
1)       abcd      IT              CTECH
2)       uvw       SAP             Informatica
```

Above is the scenario for my SQL Server 2008 table...

Can anyone help me to get output result format as shown?

Comment: Why is the `MECH` department of the `abcd` name suppressed and not shown? Given the **three** departments for `abcd` - how to decide which to show and which to ignore??

Comment: a google search on "sql server pivot query" will get you started.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways that you transform the data into columns.

You can use an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression:

```
select name,
  max(case when rn = 1 then department end) Department1,
  max(case when rn = 2 then department end) Department2,
  max(case when rn = 3 then department end) Department3
from
(
  select name,
    department,
    row_number() over(partition by name order by department) rn
  from yt
) src
group by name;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/65e91/7)

You could use a PIVOT to tranform the data from rows into columns.

```
select *
from
(
  select name,
    department,
    'Department'
        +cast(row_number() over(partition by name order by department) as varchar(10)) col
  from yt
) src
pivot
(
  max(department)
  for col in ([Department1], [Department2], [Department3])
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/65e91/10)

I would suggest using dynamic SQL to get the result since you might have an unknown number of departments per name.  The dynamic SQL code would be:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(col) 
                    from
                    (
                      select 'department'+
                        cast(row_number() over(partition by name order by department) as varchar(10)) col
                      from yt
                    ) src
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT name, ' + @cols + ' 
            from 
             (
                select name, department,
                  ''department''+
                        cast(row_number() over(partition by name order by department) as varchar(10)) col
                from yt
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(department)
                for col in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/65e91/5)

Comment: Much more expensive than while?

Comment: @kgu87 Why loop through the data when this can easily be done a different way

Comment: it's not looping through the _data_

Comment: @kgu87 But you are looping through the number of departments, that is not needed

Comment: Loops are the exact opposite of cheap.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @maxDept int
select @maxDept = max(numDepts)
from
(
    select  name, numDepts = count(dept) from depts group by name
) a

declare @deptPivot varchar(max)
set @deptPivot = ''
declare @counter int
set @counter = 1
while @counter <= @maxdept 
begin
   if (@deptPivot) = '' 
      set @deptPivot = 'department' + convert(varchar, @counter)
   else
      set @deptPivot = @deptPivot + ', department' + convert(varchar, @counter)

   set @counter = @counter + 1
end

declare @sql varchar(max)
set @sql = '
select
name, ' + @deptPivot + '
from
(
    select 
    name,
    id = ''department'' + convert(varchar, row_number() over (partition by name order by dept asc)),
    dept
    from depts
) a
pivot
(
   max(dept) for id in (' + @deptPivot + ')
) as pvt'

--print @sql
exec (@sql)
```

Comment: This can be done without using a `while`, that seems a little excessive

Comment: anyway this question doesn't deserve such a wonderful answer :) (+1)

Answer (score 0):

**Assumptions**: OP wants to consider only `top 2 Departments` for a name.

1.Create a **temp table** for `Ranking`

```
select 
ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by Name order by Name) AS ver
,Name
,Department
into #temp1
from table_name;
```

2.Now us the below `Query`

```
select 
DISTINCT 
t1.Name,
t2.Department as Department1,
t3.Department as Department2
from #temp1 t1
left join #temp1 t2 on t1.Name=t2.Name and t2.ver=1
left join #temp1 t3 on t1.Name=t3.Name and t3.ver=2
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d43b4/2)**